# C# - The underlying provider failed on Open. The current TransactionScope is already complete

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get an error and I couldn't find reason. 
The error is below:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. 
>       -> System.InvalidOperationException: The current TransactionScope is already complete.
>              at System.Transactions.Transaction.get_Current()
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetFromTransactedPool(Transaction& transaction)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>              at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>              at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>              at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>              at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>              at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
>              at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>              --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__1()
>              at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>              at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>              at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>              at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>              at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>              at DFStore.Business.Core.Helpers.Settings.GetGlobalSettingValues()
>              at DFStore.Business.Core.Helpers.Settings.GetGlobalSetting[T](String key)
>              at DFStore.ExternalSystemConnector.DocumentManagementConnector.FileDownloaderConnector.OnDoOperation(Dictionary`2 tInput)

I couldn't found anyone TransactionScope in my code:

```
using (var dbRepository = new DbRepository<ManagementDbContext>())
                {
                    listGlobalSettingValue = dbRepository.Select<GlobalSettingValue>().Include(x => x.SettingDefinition).ToList();
                }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this means that you have completed your current transaction; for example, you might have commited an update already, and then tried to execute another operation.  If you could post the code around where you access the DB (i.e. from when you open the connection to the end of the method) that would help isolate the exact line in question

Comment: I'm afraid the error message is very descriptive, there is no hidden catch. Something opened a transaction scope and it ran to completion. You will have to post a [mcve] for anybody to help properly.

Comment: If the underlying tables have been set to have tracking enabled or if the version of EF that you are using is prior 6.1 then Transaction scope was/is automatic.

Comment: This script go to EF. Also before this there isn't any TransactionScope.

Comment: EF version is 4.1.0.0

Comment: This can occur when an additional DB command (even with a new EF context) is called within a using (TransactionScope..) block but after .Complete() is called.  In other words if commands are run after Complete() but before the implicit Dispose().